# Open cover of $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that it does not have a finite subcover.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is not closed. How can I build an open cover of $A$ such that it does not have a finite subcover?

Comment: It may heavily depend on what $\;A\;$ is...

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $p\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$, and find a family of open sets $U_n$ such that $\bigcup_nU_n=\Bbb R\setminus\{p\}$; I’ve suggested a specific one in the spoiler-protected block below. Show that no finite subfamily can cover $A$.

> For instance, let $U_n=\Bbb R\setminus\left[p-\frac1n,p+\frac1n\right]$.